# Does Android(on ARM) have the hardware performance counters?

Tags: android, performance, monitor

So like in Linux on Intel processor, we have a large amount of hardware performance counters to access. Like previously, using a user-space software called [perfmon2](http://perfmon2.sourceforge.net/), I could get values of cache miss rate, CPU stalling cycles due to some reason(e.g,. L1 cache miss) and etc.

My question is , do we have those stuff in Android? Since it's based on ARM, I do not think we have as strong performance monitor counter support as we have in x86, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ARM11 and Cortex-A/R do have hardware performance counters. You can check that on the official ARM website on this page: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka4237.html

Since Android is also running on top of Linux, you can access performance counters through user-space software via the  "Perf Events" subsystem. However, you will need to write native C code, which includes "perf_event.h" and build it using the Android NDK. Before you start writing code, I suggest you take a look at this project: platform/external/linux-tools-perf (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/linux-tools-perf/), which may be exactly what you are looking for. I don't know about any alternatives which allow doing this directly from Java Code.

Comment: The link to KA4237.html has since broken.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Benny's answer, I'll add the following:

1. The linux-tools-perf project is integrated with the AOSP (I'm using 4.2).  It is under $AOSP/external/linux-tools-perf.  The ./linux-tools-perf/Documentation contains a lot of info on how to run everything.  The perf tool is built in $PRODUCT_OUT/system/bin/perf as part of the AOSP but not packaged; you need to explicitly push it to the target.
2. Check the Android (linux) kernel to confirm it supports PM: PERF_EVENTS.  Google how to get .config but easiest is running "extract-ikconfig zImage".
3. One needs to have root access on the target and then run something like "./perf stat -- testprog1" to see results.  There are a lot of arguments to the command to record/retrieve different PM counters.
4. Remember most ARM implementations have multiple cores and A LOT of pipelining.  Cortex-A9 has out-of-order execution.  So the numbers can be a little freaky - almost meaningless sometimes.
5. I use the ARM PMCCNTR register, the ARM PM Cycle Counter, occasionally to test code performance.  PMUSERENR.EN and PMINTENCLR.C must be set at PL1+ level and then PMCCNTR can be managed at PL0 level. See the ARM ARM for what all this means and the perf subsystem for example usage!

Note: All the shell vars are set up in $AOSP/build/envsetup.sh

Comment: I agree. The best way is to power of the cores from sysfs (if measuring unicore performance/single threaded) and test 2-3 time with idle system setting and then running your test. That should give a better and realistic picture.

Comment: `linux-tools-perf` is now renamed to `Simpleperf` and moved under `platform/ system/extras`(docs [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/simpleperf) and [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/simpleperf/doc/README.md)).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to use [ARM® HWCPipe Exporter](https://github.com/ylz-at/arm-hwcpipe-exporter).

[ARM® HWCPipe Exporter](https://github.com/ylz-at/arm-hwcpipe-exporter) is a Prometheus exporter written in Java and C++ that retrieves metrics from Android devices running on ARM® Hardware components and exports them to the Prometheus monitoring system.

Disclaimer: I am the author of ARM HWCPipe Exporter.