# Strange performance of avcodec_decode_video2

Tags: android, performance, ffmpeg, delay, decode

I am developing an Android video player. I use ffmpeg in native code to decode video frame. In  the native code, I have a thread called decode_thread that calls `avcodec_decode_video2()`

```
int decode_thread(void *arg) { 
   avcodec_decode_video2(codecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished,pkt);
}
```

I have another thread called display_thread that uses `aNativeWindow` to display a decoded frame on a SurfaceView.

The problem is that if I let the decode_thread run continuously without a delay. It significantly reduces the performance of `avcodec_decode_video2()`. Sometimes it takes about 0.1 seconds to decode a frame. However if I put a delay on the decode_thread. Something likes this.

```
int decode_thread(void *arg) { 
    avcodec_decode_video2(codecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished,pkt);
    usleep(20*1000);
}
```

The performance of `avcodec_decode_video2()` is really good, about 0.001 seconds. However putting a delay on the decode_thread is not a good solution because it affects the playback. Could anyone explain the behavior of avcodec_decode_video2() and suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks impossible that the performance of video decoding function would improve just because your thread sleeps. Most likely the video decoding thread gets preempted by another thread, and hence you get the increased timing (hence your thread did not work). When you add a call to `usleep`, this does the context switch to another thread. So when your decoding thread is scheduled again the next time, it starts with the full CPU slice, and is not interrupted in the `decode_ video2` function anymore.

What should you do? You surely want to decode packets a little bit ahead than you show them - the performance of `avcodec_decode_video2` certainly isn't constant, and if you try to stay just one frame ahead, you might not have enough time to decode one of the frames.

I'd create a producer-consumer queue with the decoded frames, with the top limit. The decoder thread is a producer, and it should run until it fills up the queue, and then it should wait until there's room for another frame. The display thread is a consumer, it would take frames from this queue and display them.

Comment: I use SDL_CreateThread() to create thread. Could you provide any suggestion on how to detect which thread preempts the decode_thread ?

Comment: It is not possible to detect WHICH thread is scheduled next without messing up with the OS kernel. Nor you should do so, as this may not be even your application thread, and in any case this might be a different thread every time - note that your Android OS is running many different processes, many multithreaded, and you have at most 4 CPUs in your device.

Comment: I got a feeling that you need performance counters if you're interested to measure the raw performance; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729717/does-androidon-arm-have-the-hardware-performance-counters